# Puppet Class -> Class syntax explanation

Tags: puppet

I'm looking at some puppet code below and haven't been able to find any documentation explaining the syntax. Can someone explain / point me in the right direction for documentation.

```
Class['os']  -> 
     Class['ssh']  -> 
       Class['java']  -> 
         Class['wls1036'] -> 
           Class['wls1036_domain'] ->               Class['wls_application_Cluster'] -> 
               Class['wls_application_JMS'] ->
                 Class['packdomain']
```

I believe this just says that the class os is executed before ssh and so on?

Comment: Please see [Language: Relationships and Ordering](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html).

Comment: Your interpretation is basically correct, yes. The syntax orders the classes.